# How can I use Mongrel for my non-rails ruby webapp?

Tags: ruby, mongrel

I've got a non-RoR but ruby webapp in the works.

So far, I've just been using requests, hacks, and mod_ruby; but I'd really like to try out Mongrel--which seems to work really well for RoR sites.

I looked at the examples given in GitHub, and none of them does dynamic changing of content w/o having to restart Mongrel like you can do in RoR under dev mode.

How can I do this? (Just using `load` doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) with a Mongrel backend; hello world really is as easy as it says on the front page.  I actually started with Sinatra, and then changed the server from webrick to mongrel after experimenting around with which gave better performance.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130322/why-is-my-sinatra-website-so-slow) for how that testing worked out.