# Rails server on VirtualBox is running really slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, virtualbox

My local Rails server is running excruciatingly slow. The setup: Ubuntu server in VirtualBox, and Windows can SSH and access HTTP port 3000. Memory allocated is 1.5GB, but the page is still responding really slow in my Windows 7 browser.

Any thoughts on this? (I might be one of the really few people who's using this setup...)

Comment: Can you provide some rails log entries?(development.log,etc) What are your db times vs application times? What db are you running? Is it only on the Windows 7 host? Are local requests within the Ubuntu instance fast?

Comment: Are you running on an unplugged laptop?  I have that setup, and when running on battery, something about power management slows things down ridiculously in the vm, but all is fine plugged in.

Comment: If by "responding really slow" you mean "I am waiting forever for my static files and my page loads for more than one minute", then count me in, I have the same problem.

Comment: Isn't Ruby on Rails excruciatingly slow by nature ? Are you sure it comes from the virtualization ? You should try on a native install to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by switching from Webrick to another Rails server (can't remember which one anymore), simple as that.

Webrick might not necessarily be the problem though, because later when I switched back to it, the server run just fine without any sluggishness.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could be one of a couple issues:

1. Webrick reverse DNS lookups are slowing you down: [Webrick is very slow to respond. How to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-is-very-slow-to-respond-how-to-speed-it-up)
2. You're using a VirtualBox shared folder, and vboxfs is very slow: [Rails VERY slow in development using Ubuntu VVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295298/rails-very-slow-in-development-using-ubuntu-vvm/18315468#18315468)

Answer (score 0):

After you created your vm make sure that you install the Guest Additions!

It lets you use your virtual machine at fullscreen and it also adds extras kernel modules to get better performance.

once in your VM on the above menu click devices and click insert guest editions cd image..
then go to my computer and find that image, should be cd, double click and it should load

that worked for me, good luck