# Rails 3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 under VirtualBox very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox with Ubuntu 11.10 on Windows7.
I run Rails 3.1 on webrick (rails s) and go to VirtualBox's IP adress (192.168.2.xxx:3000) from browser on Windows.
At this moment I face troubles - page loads very very slowly, on Rails console i see how slowly it responses files (css, js, images): up to 5 seconds for each!
But: if I go 0.0.0.0:3000 inside Ubuntu - it works perfect.

Where is the problem? Where to look for a solution?

Comment: What processor are you using on your host? Do you have Hardware Virtualization enabled in your BIOS?

Comment: I use one of 4 processors (core i5).
I don't know if HV is enabled, will see it later. Does it really matter?

Comment: It does matter. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webrick Very Slow When Accessing Applications From Remote Desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-very-slow-when-accessing-applications-from-remote-desktop)

Comment: Looks like you need to set Webrick's `DoNotReverseLookup` option to `true`.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, it appears this is a duplicate of another issue, though that issue specifically mentions webrick and a remote desktop connection, neither of which was I looking for, as I didn't know it was specific to webrick.

So I think it should be noted that this is **NOT** a misconfiguration of the virtual machine or BIOS settings or anything like that.  This *is strictly* a webrick issue.  Other services work just fine if they aren't trying to do reverse DNS lookups.

The problem stems from Webrick's default setting to try and do a reverse DNS lookup, which has issues when the lookup fails, as it tends to do consistently for me on my local machine.

There are a few ways to fix this.

### Hack /etc/hosts

The first is to hack `/etc/hosts` so your client machine has an entry.  Hacking `/etc/hosts` is semi-advanced, but basically amounts to figuring out what you host machine's IP address is and adding a line to your `/etc/hosts` file.  This requires root-level permissions.

- Get your IP address - this will be seen in the Rails console when you make a request, and will look something like this: `Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at Tue Aug 21 11:33:23 -0700 2012` - in this case, the IP address is 10.0.2.2.
- Add a line to `/etc/hosts` to identify that IP address: `10.0.2.2 Nerdmaster`

All should be well!

### Disable daemon

This seemed to work for some ubuntu users:

`service avahi-daemon stop`

Given you're killing a service, there may be other apps which have issues.  This is probably best as a temporary measure, not a permanent one, but I know very little about the service, so avoid taking my word for this one :)

This also requires root-level permissions.

### Hack webrick

I really despise hacking core Ruby code that I have to re-hack on every update, but this is what a lot of people do:

- Find your `webrick/config.rb`

  - It may be in `/usr/lib/ruby/[version]/webrick/config.rb` if you're running a normal Ruby
  - If you use RVM, you'll have to find the appropriate ruby directory, e.g. `/home/username/.rvm/rubies/[version]/lib/ruby/[version]/webrick/config.rb`
  - I don't know jack about other options like rbenv
  - Worst-case scenario, try `find / -type d -name "webrick"`
- Edit in your favorite editor (obviously this would be vim)

  - Look for `:DoNotReverseLookup => nil`.
  - Change `nil` to `true`.
  - If you don't see this setting, you may have to use the `/etc/hosts` hack above.

If you aren't using rvm or something similar, this will require root-level permissions.

### Don't use webrick

I don't think this is a real solution, as webrick is sometimes your best (or at least quickest) option, but you can try a different server.  Thin and mongrel seem to have good support and, based on what others with this problem are saying, appear not to do a reverse DNS lookup.  I haven't tried these approaches, so I don't know for sure how good they are.

This can be done without root-level permissions.

Comment: Hello I have a question for your answer. I met the same problem. Very slow rails inside VM using Ubuntu as template. I don't know why. If I use the first approach , hack the /etc/hosts, is that hack the /etc/hosts inside the VM machine? and the entry will be <incoming IP> <hostname of the VM machine> ??? Can you elaborate more? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Kit Ho, As I recall, hacking /etc/hosts inside the VM is what you want.  You add an entry so that Webrick knows what your "external" machine is (the host).  The name you give it isn't important so long as it has an entry it can look up.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Gemfile to add:

```
gem 'mongrel'

bundle install

rails s -> will use mongrel instead of webrick and be lightning fast.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the slowness of Rails 4 (1 second+ for each asset 304) on an Ubuntu guest VM turned out to be [Virtualbox shared folders](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868).  Found that cause in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18315468/187812), moving away from shared folders fixed the speed issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using windows10 home edition with 8 ram, 250g ssd, when I run Rails4.x (thin) on Virtual box with ubuntu server 16, I found the render time is extreamlly slow, mostly up to 4 - 5 seconds, finally I moved rails project from host shared folder to Virtualbox vm inside, it's become quite faster now.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your firewall or antivirus on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Scott's answer of just switching to mongrel, but if you're using a modern version of ruby (> 1.9.1), mongrel is no longer supported.  ([Install Mongrel in Ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851741/install-mongrel-in-ruby-1-9-3))

I switched over to thin - http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/

> sudo gem install thin
>
> thin start

and it's super snappy for me.