# Install Mongrel in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

How can I successfully install Mongrel for ruby 1.9.3

Here's the error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mongrel:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling http11_parser.c
compiling http11.c
http11.c: In function ‘http_field’:
http11.c:70:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
http11.c:71:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
http11.c:77:22: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:77:50: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
http11.c:77:27: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
http11.c: In function ‘request_uri’:
http11.c:102:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
http11.c: In function ‘fragment’:
http11.c:113:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
http11.c: In function ‘request_path’:
http11.c:124:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
http11.c: In function ‘query_string’:
http11.c:135:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
http11.c: In function ‘header_done’:
http11.c:172:13: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:172:13: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:172:13: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:174:89: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:176:52: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:177:26: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
http11.c: In function ‘HttpParser_execute’:
http11.c:298:23: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:299:23: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
http11.c:307:5: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [http11.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/ext/http11/gem_make.out
```

I already tried `sudo gem install mongrel --pre`
and even the one that has `--source`

I don't know why it isn't working. Is it compatible with Ruby 1.9.1 and up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[You are not alone.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121164448/http://isitruby19.com/mongrel) In the thread, however, there’s [a link to a possible fix](http://rubynyc.wordpress.com/ruby-1-9-1/installing-mongrel-1-1-5-on-ruby-1-9-1/). I’ve not tried it so YMMV, but it seems like a plausible fix.

Given that Mongrel is no longer being updated, though, why not switch to something like [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)?

**Edit:** Sorry, I see that you're asking about 1.9.3. My understanding is that Mongrel is (supposed to be) compatible with up to 1.9.1, but broken in 1.9.2+. Yet another good reason to switch to something more modern and maintained.

Answer (score 9):

below command,

```
gem install mongrel --pre
```

works well.

ref: [check this link for more details](http://kevin.h-pk-ns.com/2011/08/11/using-mongrel-on-ruby-1-9-2/)

Answer (score 1):

As John B stated, switch to Thin.

After not being able to get Mongrel to install with my current set up with Ruby 1.9.3, I commented out Mongrel from my Gemfile and added Thin. This let my app fully install and run great.

In my Gemfile

```
#gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'
gem 'thin'
```

then run

```
bundle install
```