# Running Rails very slow inside Virtual Box Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, virtualbox, vagrant

I have VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.04. I use Vagant to setup my environment. I run Rails 3.2.9 on thin (rails s) and go to VirtualBox's IP adrress (10.10.11.xxx:3000) from browser on my host machine. At this moment I face troubles - page loads very very slowly, on Rails console i see how slowly it responses files (css, js, images): up to 5 seconds for each! But: if I go 0.0.0.0:3000 inside Ubuntu - it works perfect.

```
Inside VM, there are two Network interface
eth0 --> it is set by Vagrant (NAT)
eth1 --> bridge, has an external IP 10.10.11.xxx
```

Where is the problem? Where to look for a solution?

People said it is related to reverse DNS lookup problem. How can I solve it? anyone has idea?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you don't place your project in synced folder (by default it uses `vboxsf` which has known performance issues when number of files/directories are large).

#### Webrick Reverse DNS Lookup

Looks like you are using Webrick (thin doesn't seem to have this problem), edit its `config.rb` to disable reverse DNS lookup to speed it up.

For rbenv managed ruby, e.g. => `~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/config.rb`

Change `:DoNotReverseLookup => nil` to `:DoNotReverseLookup => true`

> **NOTE**: People mentioned stopping the `avahi-daemon`, you can try to stop it if you use it. My understanding is that it is **NOT** installed by default on Ubuntu Server (or other base installs) (but desktop).

#### Similar problems for more details

- [Webrick is very slow to respond. How to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-is-very-slow-to-respond-how-to-speed-it-up)
- [Rails 3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 under VirtualBox very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670080/rails-3-1-on-ubuntu-11-10-under-virtualbox-very-slow)

Comment: The config file for rvm was in /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/config.rb

Answer (score 0):

Having very slow perform when running Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04 in virtualbox? It’s because Ubuntu can’t use graphics card for acceleration, ubuntu uses CPU for rendering graphics trough LLVMpipe. It makes running ubuntu in virualbox really slow. http://namhuy.net/951/how-to-fix-slow-performance-ubuntu-13-04-running-in-virtualbox.html

To check if your Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 guest is using 3D acceleration

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

You should see something like this

```
Not software rendered: no
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes
Unity 3D supported: no
```

If you see “Not software rendered” and “Unity 3D supported” both say no. This means Unity is using slow LLVMpipe.

To enable 3D supported, fist you will need to update linux-headers

```
uname -r
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now insert vitualbox guest iso from devices and to install manually

```
cd /media
ls
cd username
ls
cd VBOX*
ls
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Insert vboxvideo to /etc/modules

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Add “vboxvideo” at the end of the file

```
loop
lp
vboxvideo
```

Reboot the machine

```
sudo reboot
```