# Vagrant slowing down http requests to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, virtualbox, vagrant, apachebench

I have a project (Rails 4.0.2) that I'm currently running inside of Vagrant (1.3.5) running VirtualBox (4.3.4). The Guest OS is Debian 6.0. When I run the application on the Host OS, or I start up the Virtualbox manually, I see a dramatic improvement in responsiveness. As soon as I use 'vagrant up', performance seems to become really poor. Here are the relevant Apache Bench results:

**Apache Bench Command**

```
ab -n 10 -c 1 http://127.0.0.1:3000/application.js
```

**Host OS**

```
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:    27   44  28.3     33     118
Waiting:       25   41  28.6     31     116
Total:         27   44  28.3     33     118
```

**Virtualbox**

```
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.4      0       1
Processing:    57   71  19.1     67     119
Waiting:       46   59  19.3     57     110
Total:         57   71  19.1     68     119
```

**Vagrant**

```
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:   849  916  76.2    901    1115
Waiting:      831  892  72.6    883    1081
Total:        849  916  76.2    901    1115
```

I would expect a slowdown running the application in Virtualbox, but not an order of magnitude. I'm also not doing anything fancy with my Vagrantfile:

**Vagrantfile**

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
   config.vm.box = "squeeze"
   config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000 
end
```

I've tried the fixes specified in [this github issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1807) and [this HackerNews comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6085695) but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't place your project in synced folder (by default it uses `vboxsf` which has known performance issues with large numbers of files/directories).

This may also be related to "Webrick Reverse DNS Lookup", take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284483/1801697

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sync'ed folders were my problem. I've changed it to use NFS and it's significantly faster. Here's the documentation for it http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/nfs.html

Comment: The Webbrick config file was my problem. I've also found Vagrant rsync  is 10 times faster than vboxfs or NFS.