# Rails only responds when accessed from local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, webrick

I'm running a Rails application on a Mac Mini server machine (with Webrick, running ruby 1.9.2 using rvm). It works fine when I run it locally on my MacBook, and it *was* working before I reinstalled rvm, but now whenever I try to access it from a browser on my local machine, it simply hangs and doesn't respond.

If I do a `curl http://0.0.0.0:3000` on my server, though, I get the webpage back fine.

I created a fresh Rails app just to double-check it wasn't a problem with my app, and I get the same problem. I also get the problem with Mongrel, and if I try running a bare Sinatra app with Thin.

It sounds like the same problem documented here: [Webrick is very slow to respond. How to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-very-slow-when-accessing-applications-from-remote-desktop), but I tried modifying my `config.rb` file to use `:DoNotReverseLookup => true,` and it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is related to Rails or your dispatcher. It looks like the OS firewall is blocking ingoing requests to port 3000. Did you try to allow all ingoing connections from your System Preferences ?