# thin slow in development when not using localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, webrick

I switched to using thin in local development instead of webrick.

When I access `localhost:3000` it returns the page almost instantly just like webrick

But when I access `myapp.local:3000` the browser spins for 20 seconds or so on each request before rendering the page. I'm not sure what it's doing during that time - the rails log shows the page being generated almost instantly - it almost seems like the browser is doing name resolution during that time or something else.

In my `/etc/hosts` i have

`127.0.0.1   myapp.local`

In webrick there was no difference between accessing `myapp.local:3000` and `localhost:3000`.

But in thin there is the large difference mentioned above.  Any theories?  Much appreciated!

Comment: I found mongrel to work the best in this situation

Comment: passenger works very well for such sub domains on development for me. Give it a try: http://www.modrails.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the file /usr/lib/ruby/VERSION_OF_RUBY/webrick/config.rb and edit it.
Replace/insert the following line as a new key of the General hash.

`:DoNotReverseLookup => true`

Restart webrick.

Otherwise try running sudo service avahi-daemon stop

See [Webrick is very slow to respond. How to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-is-very-slow-to-respond-how-to-speed-it) for more details

Comment: Clarification - this solved it for webrick.  I still haven't found how to solve this problem for thin though.