# Rails 3.2 asset pipeline: Not caching on domains other than localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've come across an issue which appears to be to do with caching and the assets pipeline. The app is setup to run in development mode from `myapp.local` and various subdomains of this. These domains are just setup in my `/etc/hosts` file to point to `127.0.0.1`.

The issue is that when assets are loaded via this domain they are very slow, as if they are not being cached:

```
$ time curl http://myapp.local/assets/application.css
....
curl http://myapp.local/assets/application.css  0.01s user 0.02s system 0% cpu 5.125 total
```

If I access them over localhost, they load almost instantly:

```
$ time curl http://localhost/assets/application.css
...
curl http://localhost/assets/application.css  0.01s user 0.02s system 30% cpu 0.121 total
```

Is there a way to make the caching behave correctly when accessing it other over the custom development domains?

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-is-very-slow-to-respond-how-to-speed-it

Comment: In the end I just changed everything to myapp.localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just changed everything to myapp.localhost.